# Virtual path provided not used in ASP.NET bundles

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, virtual-path

I have the following bundle in my BundleConfig:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Basic/globalCss").Include("~/Content/Basic/global.css"));
```

I am using the following to render the CSS bundle:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/Basic/globalCss")
```

On my local machine (debug environment) the CSS file is included/loaded via its absolute path. I have compilation turned off/false for debug, so this makes sense. When I push to a QA environment (compilation turned on/true), I see the following virtual path being included in the page:

```
<link href="/Content/globalbasicCss?v=6i8x1Cxf8pXm5g9uxAk8-wcO02DFmeAgYLWpJk-3r_g1" rel="stylesheet">
```

This was the old virtual path that I had was `~/Content/globalbasicCss`.

Why is my bundle not using the new virtual path I provided `~/Content/Basic/globalCss`? Is this because there were no changes made to the CSS file included in the bundle, by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to make changes to the actual bundled CSS files in order for that bundle virtual path to update. I'm not sure why this is, and would appreciate anyone with better understanding of ASP.NET bundling explaining why this happens this way.

Answer (score 0):

That is the bundling and minification feature. Your CSS bundle is minified and if you had more files they would be bundled in one file.

This happens when you usually build in release mode with the web.config setting

```
<compilation debug="false">
```

More information here - http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification